# unable access jquery veriable in json object

Tags: jquery, json

Below is my jQuery code. I am unable to access jQuery variable inside the JSON object. When I check the console it's empty.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var sr = 0;
    var invoiceArray = [];
    var invoiceDetailArray = [];
    var customername = $("#customername").val();
    var mobnumber = $("#mobilenumber").val(); 
    var idcardno = $("#idcardno").val();
    var status = $("#status option:selected").text();
    var address = $("#address").val();
    $("#submit").click(function () {
        var invoice = {
            customername: customername,
            mobnumber: mobnumber,
            idcardno: idcardno,
            status: status,
            address: address,
        }
        invoiceArray.push(invoice);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(invoiceArray));

    })
})
```

Comment: Post your html also

Comment: you should fetch the input values INSIDE 'submit handler, not before and outside